# How can i execlude subview from parent clip in UIKit?

Tags: swift, uiview, calendarkit

In my iOS App, i am using CalendarKit, a Framework to create a full-featured Calendar. I want to modify the EventView to add rounded corners. To do that, i configure the EventView Class like this:

```swift
private func configure() {
    clipsToBounds = true
    color = tintColor
    addSubview(textView)
    
    for (idx, handle) in eventResizeHandles.enumerated() {
      handle.tag = idx
      addSubview(handle)
    }
  }
```

and i set the following properties to the view:

```swift
layer.cornerRadius = 6
```

it works but now, the rounded dots for editing/moving are clipped:

[image]

What can i do, to unclip the dots from parent view? Any ideas? I already tried to set `zPosition` but it doesn't work.

Note: The full EventView Class can be found here: https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/blob/0235dab6e9ca190a380868224d0e8fb149e6009a/Source/Timeline/EventView.swift

Comment: Looking at the code, the simplest solution is add a new subview with the background color, add rounded corners to that, and remove that `backgroundColor = event.backgroundColor` from code. A good point of reference is how `UITableViewCell` works - it has a separate `contentView` and `backgroundView`, which allow you to do things like that.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks, could you show me what i need to change? I am a newcomer of UIKit...

Comment: Please, file a bug on CalendarKit, as the UI is not customized to match the latest iOS. Put this question and all of the relevant code in the description.